# How to set up a new user account in SAS

Tags: sas

If I wish to add a new user account to SAS so that the person can access SAS EG and connect to the Application Server, in which file do I need to add the user account? The user already exists in the company wide LDAP server. Can SAS read from teh LDAP server? How to configure SAS to do that?

Comment: I think this is technically something that belongs at [SF], not Stack Overflow, since it's server administration.

Comment: @Joe I don't think Server Fault would be appropriate; it has nothing to do with network administration.  This really is a question about configuring the SAS BI Server environment.

Comment: Per the close reason: "Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault."  This is clearly not about programming, but about server administration, which is explicitly what SF is for.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about administering a software application, and not about a programming problem.

Comment: FYI, I posted this as a question on [meta] [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210849/server-administration-versus-programming-tools), and it sounds like this doesn't really have a proper home on StackExchange.  It's not a programming problem so it doesn't belong here, but [SF] isn't really appropriate either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to run SAS Management Console and connect to your SAS Metadata Server using the account sasadm@saspw.  This account should have unrestricted access in metadata.  Once into the SMC, find the User Manager plugin in the left hand tree.  Click on it and see the list of user objects known to SAS.  Create a new user object for each user who wants to connect.  You will need to assign groups and roles as needed for the job function (see SAS BI Admin documentation for details).

Once you have done this, the final piece is to add a Login for the user to associate the user object to an operating system account.  In the typical case the metadata server uses DefaultAuth domain and associates the login account with the operating system account.  This can, in turn, be a user account in LDAP if your operating system makes the connection of the local system accounts to LDAP.

Does your operating system link local (or domain) accounts to LDAP?  For example, using a windows active directory domain controller means that the operating system accounts are one and the the same as Active Directory (which is an LDAP server).

Comment: The key point here is that the work must be done by the site SAS Administrator, who should already know how to do thing like this.  Victor should contact that person for help.